# Unable to connect to Localdb in SQL Sever 2014 (v12.0.2000.8) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am working on Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.2000.8) and servername "ubaid" - I can connect to SQL Server using this connection string:

```
Data source = ubaid;User Id=sa;password=mycode;Database=user_management_system;integrated security=true
```

This string is working correctly, but when I want to connect using `data source=localdb`, then an error occurs.

The connection string I tried is:

```
Data source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; User Id =sa;password=mycode;Database=user_management_system;integrated security=true
```

The other is:

```
Data source = (localdb)\ProjectsV12; User Id =sa;password=mycode;Database=user_management_system;integrated security=true
```

Both are causing an error. How can I resolve this problem and make connection string with localdb?

Comment: Run this from the command prompt and add the result to your question: `sqllocaldb info`

Comment: result is "MSSQLLocalDB"

Comment: What error message is returned with `Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`? You might try `sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB`.

Comment: i try this and show  "localdb instance "MSSQLLocalDB" started." in cmd prompt.. but now the error occured "Cannot open database "user_management_system" requested by the login. The login failed." on con.open line.

Comment: also "Login failed for user 'ubaid\Ubaid Ullah'."

Comment: The "cannot open database" error means that either the database does not exist or the user (Ubaid\ubaid) does not have permissions to use it. It shouldn't be connecting with that user since you have `user id = sa` in the connection string (which shouldn't be used for routine application connections).

Comment: database exists..and i don't now how to give permission to use it..help me to give permission.

Comment: Why is the app attempting to connect as user `Ubaid\Ubaid` when you have `sa` in the connection string? You could use SSMS to manage the LocalDB security.